# Calculate the value of $ l$

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

A triangular pyramid is based on a triangle of sides $13$ cm, $14$ cm and $15$ cm; the other edges measure $ 1 $. Knowing the volume of the pyramid is $ 105 \sqrt {22} $ $ cm ^ 3 $, the value of $ l $, in cm, is equal to:

What I tried: I tried to calculate the perimeter to apply Herón's formula. So I found 84 in the area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.

The foot of the height of the pyramid is the circumcenter of the base. Find height $h$ of the pyramid from volume and base area, then find circumradius $r$ of the base. You have then:
$$
l=\sqrt{h^2+r^2}.
$$